# Sum of elements (can be repeated) of subarrays equal to a target value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sum, target

```
def howSum(targetSum, numbers):
    if targetSum == 0:
        return []
    if targetSum < 0:
        return None
    for num in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum - num
        remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers)
        if remainderResult != None:
            return [remainderResult, num]
    return None
```

I have tried this code and getting the answer [[[[[], 2], 2], 2], 2] instead of [2, 2, 2, 2]. I am quite new to programming and stack exchange. Please help me out here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sequence unpacking.

Instead of:

```
            return [remainderResult, num]
```

Use:

```
            return [*remainderResult, num]
```

Full code:

```
def howSum(targetSum, numbers):
    if targetSum == 0:
        return []
    if targetSum < 0:
        return None
    for num in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum - num
        remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers)
        if remainderResult != None:
            return [*remainderResult, num]
    return None'
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```